# Keycloak Example with Mysql datasource - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: hibernate, keycloak, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to master Keycloak Custom User Storage SPI with the example provide in the following link https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/user-storage-simple

I have used Hibernate to load com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in order to configure the datasource in my persistence.xml file

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="keycloak-spi-v1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.patrickhub.ch.keycloakspiv1.entity.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloakspidb?useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I used entityManager EntityManagerFactory class to get EntityManager as the transaction-type equal to RESOURCE_LOCAL.

```
private EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("keycloak-spi-v1").createEntityManager()
```

I have also declared  java-sql-connection dependencies and others as follow

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ch.patrickhub.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-spi-v1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description> </description>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
         <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
         <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax</groupId>
          <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
          <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean package`, everything build find and I even succeed to deploy into keycloak and create a User federation with my jar.
But when i try to view all users i get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:163)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:119)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        ... 172 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:131)
        ... 184 more
```

Please can anyone help ?

Comment: Please have a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587013/mysql-and-keycloak-setup

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deploy a jar which is trying to access third party libraries like Hibernate. Instead try to create an .ear file and then deploy using wildfly to jBoss. Below reference really helped me solve similar problem I was facing.

https://github.com/Linch1/mysql-keycloak-storage-spi

It also has provided complete steps on how to deploy the respective .ear created in the process. Go through it once.